# AJAX Cross Domain request to WCF service without using jsonp

Tags: ajax, json, wcf

I am using a WCF service and currently it is consumed by a Silverlight application. The WCF service has clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml which is why there is no issue with making request from Silverlight even though the request comes from a different domain.

Now my understanding is that, adding following line of code on WCF service's web config built using .net 4.0 or above allows to make cross domain request using `jsonp`

`<standardendpoint crossdomainscriptaccessenabled="true">`

However, jsonp won't resolve my issue as I need to add custom request headers which jsonp doesn't allow as it's not really making XMLHttpRequest.

I am wondering, if I edit `global.asax` of WCF service with following snippet of code, will I be able to make AJAX cross domain request successfully?

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EnableCrossDomainAjaxCall();
}

private void EnableCrossDomainAjaxCall()
{
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

  if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
  {
   HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
   HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-        Type, Accept");
   HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
   HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
  }
}
```

Please note that I am having issue deploying the WCF project so I just wanted to know I am taking the right approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EnableCrossDomainAjaxCall();
}

private void EnableCrossDomainAjaxCall()
{
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

  if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS") 
  {
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, Foo");
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
  HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
 }
```

}

did the trick.

In my case, I also had to add one custom header named Foo as an example as I had to pass that from client side.

Hope it helps someone!